# Show and hide tab content on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I currently have the following setup - https://jsfiddle.net/scwbqffo/
Clicking on either tab would display content and switch between tabs (Not sure why it's not working in the fiddle but works fine on my site).

I'd like to be able to click on the tab again to close it if possible?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul#tabs li").click(function(e){
        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
            var tabNum = $(this).index();
            var nthChild = tabNum+1;
            $("ul#tabs li.active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $("ul#tab li.active").removeClass("active");
            $("ul#tab li:nth-child("+nthChild+")").addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<ul id="tabs">
    <li>Show tab 1</li>
    <li>Show tab 2</li>

</ul>
<ul id="tab">
    <li>showing tab 1 content</li>
    <li>showing tab 2 content</li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul#tabs {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
ul#tabs li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #252525;
    border-bottom: solid 2px grey;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul#tabs li:hover {
    background-color: grey;
}
ul#tabs li.active {
    background-color: #00aeef;
}
ul#tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul#tab li {
    display: none;
}
ul#tab li.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: it's not working on jsfiddle because jquery isn't included

Comment: add j query min file https://jsfiddle.net/scwbqffo/5/

Comment: You mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/scwbqffo/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `else` in your jquery that removes the `active` class

```
else {
  $(this).removeClass('active');
  $("ul#tab li.active").removeClass("active");
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scwbqffo/7/)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing jQuery in the jsFiddle, to answer your question you just need to use toggleClass